# Function whose output is function in Julia

Tags: function, julia

I am Julia user.
I want to define a function whose output is a function.
This is an example.

```
function get_f(p::Int)
    if p == 1
         return f(x) = x^2
    else
         return f(x) = cos(x)
    return f
end
```

But it does not work!

```
f(x) = get_f(2)
f(2)
# UndefVarError x not defined.
```

Also, when I run the code, we have the following WARNING.

```
WARNING: Method definition f(Int64) in module Main at REPL[88]:4
```

What is the problem? If you know another good way, please tell me.
I guess we can write more sophisticated code using 'struct', but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

We should use anonymous functions.

```
function get_f(p::Int)
   if p == 1
        return (x,y) -> x+y
   elseif p == 2
        return (x,y) -> norm(x-y)
   else
        return (x,y) -> x*y
   end
end

f = get_f(2)
f(3,2) # 1.0
```

It works!

Comment: "anonymous" functions is their standard name more than "unnamed" functions...

Comment: Internally, the closures here have different types. So, this approach is type unstable: the return type depends on argument **value**. I would consider to dispatch on [`Val` types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#%22Value-types%22).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you mind posting an example using `Val`?